# ECONNREFUSED error when trying to retrieve a local json file

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, nightwatch.js

Im working with nightwatchjs and I need to perform some API calls.

In order to construct the request for a POST API call I need to retrieve a local json.

So that I

```
function retrieveJsonFile(path){
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var archivoTxt = new XMLHttpRequest();
    archivoTxt.open("GET", path, false);
    archivoTxt.send(null);
    console.log(archivoTxt);
}
```

When path is

> 'create.json'

What is logged on the console

```
{ UNSENT: 0,
  OPENED: 1,
  HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2,
  LOADING: 3,
  DONE: 4,
  readyState: 4,
  onreadystatechange: null,
  responseText: undefined,
  responseXML: '',
  status: 0,
  statusText:
   { errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 80 },
  withCredentials: false,
  open: [Function],
  setDisableHeaderCheck: [Function],
  setRequestHeader: [Function],
  getResponseHeader: [Function],
  getAllResponseHeaders: [Function],
  getRequestHeader: [Function],
  send: [Function],
  handleError: [Function],
  abort: [Function],
  addEventListener: [Function],
  removeEventListener: [Function],
  dispatchEvent: [Function] }
```

I missed about what I am doing wrong here. 
Can this be related to the default ip address?
Any clue about this error for this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Your path needs to be an URL that serves the file. You cannot just load a file from JavaScript by simply using its relative path.

Have you tried a simple  :

```
var json = require('./create.json');
```

You could also try using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API to read directly from your browser.

Here's an example for an image :

```
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var imageType = /image.*/;

if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "";

    // Create a new image.
    var img = new Image();
    // Set the img src property using the data URL.
    img.src = reader.result;

    // Add the image to the page.
    fileDisplayArea.appendChild(img);
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
} else {
  fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "File not supported!";
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion it doesn't work. The error displayed is '''Error: Cannot find module '/create.json''''. On the other hand I am trying to retrieve a file independently
 on the browser.

Comment: It depends where your `create.json` file is. If it is in the same directory as your JS file you should be fine. If it is somewhere else you need to put the path relative to your JS file.